# issue occurs when doing in LandscapeLeft

Tags: iphone

I am working to support the rotation screen in Iphone now and running into the issue. When the screen is in Poitrait mode, the position of navigation bar and its items on it looks perfectly.

When I switch to LandscapeToLeft, the width of navigation bar is stretched and it is fine.However, the position of items bar on it stay the same...Their positions are not changed at all.Therefore, there are huge room  from the rightmost button to a right margin. ...I cant not attach any images so that you guys can easily see it....Sorry about that

If you were experiencing it before, please help
Any ideas are welcomed here. Thanks

PS: these itemBarButton are added by drag and drop in the toolbar in StoryBoard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at adding a "Fixed Space Bar Button Item" or "Flexible Space Bar Button Item". You can drag them into the navigation bar from the object library.